# How to detect the socket server authorization failure on client side in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, cookies, websocket, socket.io

I want to connect an js socket client to socket.io server using
 `socket = io.connect()`. But on server side i m using `io.use()` method to check whether this socket connection contains cookies or not. I restrict the request on socket server to make connection if socket initial handshake does not contain cookies. by passing 
`next(new Error("Authentication Error"))`. But i m not able to catch this error on client side. I want to notify the client of invalid login session and login again.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Andrey... I  got success with

```
socket.on("error", function()
{
   //function to perform on occurance of authorisation failure
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to listen on `connect_error`:

```
socket.on('connection_error', function(data) {
    // data here should be an Error object sent by server
});
```

The documentation is awful, but here is a little hint (found [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace)):

`Errors passed to middleware callbacks are sent as special error
packets to clients.`